# A small clarification

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

Could you please explain the following result?

$$n\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nf \left(\frac{i}{n}\right)-\sum_{i=1}^n \int^\frac{i}{n}_\frac{i-1}{n}f(x)dx \right)=n\sum_{i=1}^n\int^\frac{i}{n}_\frac{i-1}{n}\left(f\left(\frac{i}{n}\right)-f(x)\right)dx$$
My problem is that while getting to second from first, I get $f(x)$ instead of $f\left(\frac{i}{n}\right)$. Is not
$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nf \left(\frac{i}{n}\right)=\int_o^1f(x)dx$$ and should not the whole expression reduce to $0$?

Comment: To get from the rhs to the lhs, all you need is $\int_a^bf(t)dx=(b-a)f(t)$. Note that $t$ does not depend on $x$, so $f(t)$ is constant here.

Comment: Normally $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nf \left(\frac{i}{n}\right)<\int_o^1f(x)dx$ . As $n \to \infty$ we get $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nf \left(\frac{i}{n}\right)=\int_o^1f(x)dx$.

Comment: @julien. thanks. great. missed that $f(i/n)$ is constant and took it as reimann sum. thanks.

Comment: @Argha Depending on $f$, the Riemann sums can be greater, equal, or less than the integral. The three cases can occur. Take $f(x)=x$ for instance, your inequality is actually in the other direction.

Comment: @julien: Oh sorry. you are right. I only thought $f(x)>0$.

Comment: @Argha It is not about the sign of $f$. One usually gets such inequalities when considering mototonic functions.

Comment: @user1709828 Now that you found your problem, maybe you could write an answer and accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Julien Said:

```
    To get from the rhs to the lhs, all you need is $\int^b_af(t)dx=(b−a)f(t)$.
 Note that t does not depend on x, so f(t) is constant here.
```

Which is sufficient to get to LHS from RHS. where $$\frac{1}{n}f(\frac{i}{n})=\int^{\frac{i}{n}}_{\frac{i-1}{n}}f\left(\frac{i}{n}\right)dx$$